# Do not return collection with hasMany Laravel eager loading

Tags: php, laravel

## Issue

I have a `getFacilitySettings()` function in the Facility model. This function gets all the settings and uses eager loading to get `override_settings` with it. I then use the query builder to only receive this facilities overridden settings. `Settings` **has many** `overrideSettings`, but in theory, this should only retrieve **one** record from the `override_settings` table.

```php
// App/Models/Facility.php
public function getFacilitySettings()
{
    // all settings with overridden settings for this facility
    return Settings::with(['overrideSettings' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('related_id', $this->uuid)
            ->where('related_type', Facility::class)
            ->first();
    }])->get();
}
```

My issue is that even though I added `->first();` to my `$query` I still get a collection of `overrideSettings`. I am assuming it is because of my `hasMany` relationship (see setup below). In my logs I can see the collection, expressed by `0 =>`. to access this I would have to use `settings['override_settings'][0]['value']`

```
array (
  'uuid' => '<setting uuid 0000>',
  'name' => 'login_timeout',
  'data_type' => 'integer',
  'default_value' => '5',
  'override_settings' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'uuid' => '<override uuid 1111>',
      'settings_id' => '<setting uuid 0000>',
      'value' => '69',
      'related_id' => '<facility uuid 2222>',
      'related_type' => 'App\\Models\\Facility',
    ),
  ),
)
```

## Question

Is it possible to use `first()` in the query builder, with predefined relationships like `hasMany`? If not, how can I access this the `value` in `override_settings` without the collection. Or am I going about this the wrong way?

```php
// This:
settings['override_settings']['value']

// instead of this:
settings['override_settings'][0]['value']
```

## Setup

I have three models:

- Setting
- OverrideSetting
- Facility

This is the table structure:

```
Table: settings
* uuid (Primary Key)
* name
* data_type
* default_value

Table: override_settings
* uuid (Primary Key)
* settings_id (Foreign Key)
* value
* related_id
* related_type

Table: facility
* uuid (Primary Key)
* ... (Other things not important)
```

**Important**

`override_settings` table uses a polymorphic relationship to allow multiple models (such as `Facility` and `User`) to override settings from the `settings` table. The `override_settings` table has two columns for this purpose:

- related_id: This column holds the primary key (uuid) of the model (Facility or User) that overrides the setting.
- related_type: This column stores the class name of the related model, indicating which model is performing the override (`Facility::class` or `User::class`).

Here are the relationships:

```php
// Setting.php
public function overrideSettings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OverrideSettings::class, 'all_settings_id', 'uuid');
}

// OverrideSetting.php
public function facility()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Facility::class, 'related_id', 'uuid');
}

public function setting()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AllSettings::class, 'all_settings_id', 'uuid');
}

// Facility.php
public function overrideSettings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\OverrideSettings::class, 'related_id', 'uuid')
        ->where('related_type', Facility::class);
}
```

To be clear there is not a direct relationship with the `Facility` and `Setting` models. The only relationship is through the `override_settings` table.

### EDIT

In my first iteration of OverrideSetting I called it RelatedSettings. I refactored code to change RelatedSettings to OverrideSettings, but forgot to do it in my relationships. It is now fix.

Comment: You are eager loading, do not use `->first()`, you can try using `->limit(1)` but I am not sure if it will be able to limit the returning data (it will still ALWAYS be a collection, it is a HasMany relationship)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new relationship to load one of many like:

```
public function oldestRelatedSetting()
{
    return $this->hasOne(RelatedSettings::class, 'all_settings_id', 'uuid')->oldestOfMany();
}
```

OR

```
public function latestRelatedSetting()
{
    return $this->hasOne(RelatedSettings::class, 'all_settings_id', 'uuid')->latestOfMany();
}
```

Then you can eager load by applying where()

Comment: I just realized that I changed the name of `RelatedSettings` to `OverrideSettings` but forgot to do so in the my relations. I am going to edit my question to be consistent with everything else.

Comment: Because there is no direct relationship between Facility and Settings, I do not have a facility->uuid that I can filter like my original function: `$query->where('related_id', $this->uuid)`. Is it possible (or correct) to pass the uuid into the relationship? like this? `public function latestRelatedSetting(string facility_id)`

Comment: It works with a few work-arounds. first because I am using Laravel 9 and PostgreSQL, I cannot use `latestOfMany` found [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/37854). So I just used `hasOne()` and did not use `ofMany`, because I know there will only be one record return with this code `return $this->hasOne(OverrideSettings::class, 'settings_id', 'uuid')->where('related_type', Facility::class)->where('related_id', auth()->user()->facility_id);`